# Recommendation for cross platform mobile software

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform

Good day, is there any recommendation for android or ios cross platform software other than XAMARIN ?

Comment: " Recommendation for cross platform mobile software" Stackoverflow is not a place to ask such questions. Please read the guidelines

Comment: @NizaSiwale Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Top 7 Hybrid Mobile App Frameworks Ionic Framework is in first place., Refer the following Link,

> https://www.sitepoint.com/top-7-hybrid-mobile-app-frameworks/

It's providing native Look to our Hybrid App.

Refer the following Link,

> http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/

Comment: Thanks for recommendation

Answer (score 2):

Ionic framework is the best cross  platform follow this link http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/), it's open source and supports more platforms than all others combined.

Check out 3rd party objective comparison in [property cross](http://propertycross.com/) where it beats the competition hands down in app size, lines of code and setup complexity.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Codename One, i will find more abt it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , there is Flutter by google .
  https://flutter.io
 You can develop multiplatform app with single codebase .

Comment: You can also try phonegap by adobe . https://build.phonegap.com

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate it. @Rishabh Maurya

Comment: Its my pleasure .

Comment: @ShunJian As ionic framework is based on HTML , it does not feel like a normal native android app . But flutter is very advanced .  Check this app and you will see the difference :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.flutter.gallery